# how to get category count from the follow sub category by user in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Hi i am create one query for get category count in which some period of time date. in my database i have 3 table first is category , subcategory ,  subcategoryfollow. now i want to who user follow sub category then i want to count for category. for ex user A follow 3 sub category for category 1 then user B follow same 3 sub category for category 1 then i want category 1 for count is getting 2 like this want result in the query but don't getting this type result.

Here is my query =>

```
select count(*) as Count,categroyName from categroy s inner join 
(
    select SS.categroyId from subcategory ss 
    inner join 
    ( 
        select count(*) as count,subcategoryId from subcategoryfollow SSS
        WHERE SSS.IsFollowed = 1  and CAST(SSS.InsertDateTime as date) >=  CAST('2017-07-21' as date)
        AND CAST(SSS.InsertDateTime as date) <= CAST('2017-07-22' as date)
        group by SSS.subcategoryId,SSS.UserId
    ) as tab on tab.subcategoryId = ss.subcategoryId group by SS.subcategoryId
)  as res on res.categroyId = s.categroyId where s.IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY res.categroyId,categroyName
```

This is my current o/p =>

```
Count | categroyName
1       playing 
1       Reading
```

This is my exepected o/p =>

```
Count | categroyName
2       playing 
1       Reading
```

this is my query and result. now in my table playing category store 3 sub category like cricket,football,wallyball now 2 user follow this 3 sub category so i want count 2 for the palying category. so please any one know how can do that.

Comment: @Gericke can you please help me on this query?

Comment: Try removing res.CategoryId from the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @Gericke no still getting same result.

Comment: What is the result that you get for inner most select?

Comment: i am getting just category id from the inner join

Comment: Remove the count() in the statement

Comment: no still getting same result

Comment: The most inner select count(*) as count,subcategoryId

Comment: yes i have remove that but still getting same result

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Count,categroyName FROM categroy s 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SS.categroyId FROM subcategory ss 
    INNER JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT subcategoryId FROM subcategoryfollow SSS
        WHERE SSS.IsFollowed = 1  
        AND CAST(SSS.InsertDateTime AS date) >= CAST('2017-07-21' as date)
        AND CAST(SSS.InsertDateTime AS date) <= CAST('2017-07-22' as date)
    ) AS tab on tab.subcategoryId = ss.subcategoryId 
    GROUP BY SS.subcategoryId
)  AS res on res.categroyId = s.categroyId WHERE s.IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY categroyName
```

Comment: getting error like this "Column 'subcategory.categroyId ' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."